# add geom vline and ggplotly to a facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

is there any way i could add a vertical line in both the plot at x=15. and also add a plotly to this. i tried but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks

```
sbucks_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= category, y= bad_fat, color= category)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(~ milk_dummy)+
  labs(title= "Unhealthy Fats in Milk drinks by Category",
       x= "Drinks Category",
       y="Bad Fats (g)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible dataset? If you run `dput(sbucks_new)` and paste the output into your question people will be more able/willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use geom_hline for plotting the vertical line (confusing due to the coord_flip).

Here's an example with mtcars:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb), y=disp)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~am2) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=300)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Not sure about your other question, but you can quickly convert ggplot object into plotly using ggplotly function.

```
plotly::ggplotly(p)
```